# preg_replace returning null after encountering ó (acute o)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm reading in and parsing a CSV file which is in ANSI. Before I parse it I want to remove any characters not in a whitelist

```
// remove any odd characters from string
$match_list = "\x{20}-\x{5f}\x{61}-\x{7e}"; // basic ascii chars excluding backtick
$match_list .= "\x{a1}-\x{ff}"; // extended latin 1 chars excluding control chars
$match_list .= "\x{20ac}\x{201c}\x{201d}"; // euro symbol & left/right double quotation mark (from Word)
$match_list .= "\x{2018}\x{2019}"; // left/right single quotation mark (from word)

$cleaned_line = preg_replace("/[^$match_list]/u", "*",$linein);
```

Problem is that it is returning NULL when it gets to a line which has the ó (acute o) character in it. According to my text editor this is xF3 so should be allowed.

Why is it throwing an error in preg_replace?

Update - it seems to be something to do with the file - if I copy and paste the problem line from the CSV file into my PHP file it works OK.

Update 2 - using preg_last_error()  I was able to determine the error is:

```
 PREG_BAD_UTF8_ERROR    Returned by preg_last_error() if the last error was caused by malformed UTF-8 data (only when running a regex in UTF-8 mode).
```

My text editor just reported the file as being ANSI, but using the unix file command I get this:

```
% file PRICE_LIST_A.csv
PRICE_LIST_A.csv: Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

% file DOLLARS_PRICE_LIST.csv
DOLLARS_PRICE_LIST.csv: ISO-8859 text, with CRLF line terminators

% file PRICE_LIST_B.csv
PRICE_LIST_B.csv: Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

% file PRICE_LIST_TEST.csv
PRICE_LIST_TEST.csv: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

So it seems I've been supplied files with various encodings from the same accounting application. I guess these are not valid Unicode

Comment: Why preg replace? Won't str_replace work for static replacements anymore?

Comment: It seems to [work](http://ideone.com/N4SzsB).

Comment: str_replace does not match patterns?

Comment: Show output of `var_dump($linein);` otherwise code is working fine.

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew thanks, but it is returning NULL for me. PHP 5.6 on Unix

Comment: @anubhava - rather not post actual output as it's s client's pricelist, but showing as a string(66) - And, var_dump($cleaned_line); is NULL

Comment: @Kevin what pattern are you talking about? Maybe I don't understand, but you try to replace certain "symbols" with `*`. What is the pattern? There is no pattern in replacing single symbols. https://3v4l.org/Ee63r

Comment: So clients pricelist can't be masked in any way so that we can see the real data?

Comment: @Andreas the pattern is in $match_list.

Comment: But it's not a pattern is it? It's just single symbols you want to replace? A pattern is something that HAS to be in a specific order. Your matchlist is only a list of symbols to replace, if you reverse your matchlist then it would not make any difference, right? Then it's not a pattern. See the difference?

Answer (score 0):

An invalid subject `$linein` will match nothing when you use `/u` ([PCRE_UTF8](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) modifier). To fix this make sure that the string you're passing is UTF-8.

If your string is encoded with ISO-8859-1 try this to convert to UTF8:

```
$cleaned_line = preg_replace( "/[^$match_list]/u", "*", utf8_encode($linein) );
```

Otherwise, check out the [mb_convert_encoding()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding) function.